# Get the value inside Nested Tables and Divs using VBA

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have tried multiple solutions posted around and yet to get the code working.
I would like to copy/paste value from a website into an Excel Sheet.
Here is some of the HTML: The value I am after is all the way at the bottom.

```
<DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%" ID="oReportDiv">
    <DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
        <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
            <TR>
                <TD ID="oReportCell">
                    <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
                        <TR>
                            <TD class="a106xBc">
                                <DIV class="a106xB">
                                    <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" BORDER="0" COLS="9" LANG="en-US" class="r10">


                                        <TR VALIGN="top">

                                            <TD COLSPAN="3">
                                                <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0" COLS="4" BORDER="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;" class="a103">


                                                    <TR VALIGN="top">
                                                        <TD style="HEIGHT:5.33mm;" class="a67c r14">&nbsp;</TD>
                                                        <TD style="" class="a71c">
                                                            <DIV style="word-wrap:break-word;text-decoration:none;" class="a71">Get This Value</DIV>
                                                        </TD>

<TR VALIGN="top">
                                                        <TD style="HEIGHT:5.33mm;" class="a67c r14">&nbsp;</TD>
                                                        <TD style="" class="a71c">
                                                            <DIV style="word-wrap:break-word;text-decoration:none;" class="a71">Second Value and so on</DIV>
                                                        </TD>

                                                    </TR>
```

Here is what I have tried and getting an error : 
Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub GrabLastNames()

'dimension (set aside memory for) our variables
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim div
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long


'start a new browser instance
Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
'make browser visible
objIE.Visible = True





'navigate to page with needed data
objIE.navigate ""
'wait for page to load
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
y = 1

'look at all the 'tr' elements in the 'table' with id 'myTable',
'and evaluate each, one at a time, using 'ele' variable
Set nodeList = objIE.document.querySelectorAll("td.a71c .a71")
```

For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
    Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).innerText
Next
        For Each ele In   objIE.document.getElementById("oReportDiv").getElementsById("a71")

```
    Debug.Print ele.textContent
    'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
    'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
    'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
    'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("C" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
    'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
    Sheets("Sheet3").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(3).textContent
    'increment row counter by 1
    y = y + 1
'repeat until last ele has been evaluated
Next

'save the Excel workbook
ActiveWorkbook.Save
```

End Sub

Thanks for the feedback

Comment: On which line of code does the error happen?

Comment: @ArcherBird, For Each ele In objIE.document.getElementById("oReportDiv").getElementsById("a71"). I tested the code using simple html table and it worked, but not with the above html

Comment: maybe try something like `...objIE.document.querySelector("div[class=oReportDiv] div[class=a71]")...`

Comment: @ArcherBird object required error

Comment: Edit: try `...objIE.document.querySelectorAll("div[class=oReportDiv] div[class=a71]")...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Dim nodeList As Object, i As Long
Set nodeList = objIE.document.querySelectorAll("td.a71c .a71")
For i = 0 To nodeList.Length -1
    Debug.Print nodeList.item(i).innerText
Next
```

Or

```
Set nodeList objIE.document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a71")
```

and then same loop as above.

Is there a parent iframe/frame to be handled would be another thought.

---

Full code something like:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GrabLastNames()
    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer, t As Date, nodeList As Object, i As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    With objIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://jetblue.rosterapps.com/GenerateReport.aspx?command=6Rqw0HG%2FJQvTea2EXxyC%2BSDRGUzjdE2GHNUaN5rcKVPdKRpHBhRkfYa3c%2FnPLk58WnTYk6kBq1OZHQYsWqgM8g%3D%3D&action=render"

        Do While .Busy = True Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set nodeList = .document.querySelectorAll("#oReportCell .a71")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do

        Loop While nodeList Is Nothing

        If Not nodeList Is Nothing Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3")
                For i = 0 To nodeList.Length - 1
                    .Cells(1, i + 1) = nodeList.item(i).innerText
                Next
            End With
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Am I getting rid of the loop For Each ele In ?

Comment: ops, didn't paste the whole html. Updated it. They are more element within same table

Comment: Rather than editing into your question, what happened when you used my code after the  Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

Comment: Where the correct values printed to the immediate window ? (Ctrl + G)

Comment: it pasted the values but I would like to be as follow: value1 in A1, value2 in A2 and so on

Comment: Switch to .Cells( i + 1, 1) = nodeList.item(i).innerText