# Get data from inside a div/table

Tags: excel, vba

@QHarr answered my question here [Get the value inside Nested Tables and Divs using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53109796/get-the-value-inside-nested-tables-and-divs-using-vba) regarding the values inside the nested tables and it worked great. Now I realize that not all the data are getting pulled. Here is what I thought my HTML was:

```
<body style="BORDER: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING: 0px">
  <DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
    <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
       <TR>
          // This TD was solved by @QHarr
          <TD ID="oReportCell">
          Some tables and values.  @QHarr already solved this part
          </TD>
       </TR>
     </TABLE>

  </DIV>

</body>
```

But when I realized that not all the data were pulling I checked the HTML I found out that not all the data are inside the ID="oReportCell"
So, HTML looks like this:

```
<body style="BORDER: 0px; MARGIN: 0px; PADDING: 0px">
  <DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
    <TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
       <TR>
          // This TD was solved by @QHarr

        <TD ID="oReportCell">
          Some tables and values.  @QHarr already solved this part
          </TD>
       </TR>
     </TABLE>

  </DIV>

<DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
   <TR>
      <TD ID="oReportCell">
      Some tables and values.
      </TD>
   </TR>
 </TABLE>
```

```
<DIV style="HEIGHT:100%;WIDTH:100%;" class="ap">
<TABLE CELLSPACING="0" CELLPADDING="0">
   <TR>
      <TD ID="oReportCell">
      Some tables and values.
      </TD>
   </TR>
 </TABLE>
```

```
</body>
```

They are 14 of Class="ap", and when the code is executed sometime it gets the first one. Sometime the second and so on. It doesn't get all the value.

I need to get everything that is inside class ="a92" and class="a69"

here is the full html:
I can't use pastebin due to the size of the file:

[enter link description here](http://www.tafriqt.com/report.html)

here is one of the .ap

[enter link description here](https://pastebin.com/vgsNXDdw)

Comment: For the example shown above, it seems ap is not within #oReportCell and in fact the selector becomes .ap, #oReportCell   .  __Selecting for everything inside a92 and a69__ would be querySelectorAll(".a92, .a69")

Comment: @QHarr I updated the link. You have to look at view source. #oReportCell  is only present in the first .ap, not all of them.Also, I added .ap pastebin

Comment: We need the actual html not the view source. If in chrome press F12 then select the top html tag and right click copy element

Comment: @QHarr That's how I did it the first place. I pasted it inside a file, rename its extension to html, and I uploaded it. Looking at the view page source gives me exactly what pressing F12 does.

Comment: They may be different. https://www.codebyamir.com/blog/view-source-vs-inspect-element

Comment: @QHarr here is the code in a txt file:  http://www.tafriqt.com/1report.txt

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184073/discussion-between-qharr-and-sifaks-agizul).